# Same element with click and drag and drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, slideshow, draggable

I have a slideshow with images where it goes right/left to the next image with drag and drop.

But I'm having difficulties when I put a href in the images to open a lightbox window.

Here you can see an example:

http://www.digitalpersone.com.br/slide/Example_8.html

When I click in the image, the lightbox is shown, but when I drag and drop, the same happens.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the jquery draggable? if so, it adds a css class 'ui-draggable-dragging' when you drag.

Inside the click event, you can then check if that class exist and exit the method.

```
$(function(){
    $div = $('#content'); // <div id="content">click me</div>
    $div.draggable();  
    $div.on('click', function(){
        if ($div.hasClass('.ui-draggable-dragging')) {
              return;
        }
        alert('clicked');
  });

})
```

Example here: http://jsbin.com/ayoqiw/10/

Comment: Hi uv_man! Thanks for your answer! In fact the problem is more complicated. I got Transluced plugin and I'm trying to do this implementation, as you can see here: http://www.digitalpersone.com.br/slide/Example_8.html